# Getting a random String from a List

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I am trying to create a list of words and I want to randomly pick one to use in a String. Here is what I currently have:

```
private List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
public void someMethod() {
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "string3");
    for (String s : words) {
        // What now? How would I pick a random string from the list
        // Also, if I shouldn't loop through the words, please tell me
        System.out.println(randomString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random `int` between 0 and the size of the list, and then get the element at that index.

```
words.addAll(Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "string3");
String randomString = words.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, words.size()));
```

[`ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(origin, bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) returns a pseudorandom int value between the specified origin (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).

Comment: That's a good one, I think best solution for OP's requirement.